# Parametric equation of a curve find tangent vector

Tags: calculus, parametric, tangent-line

The parametric equations of a curve are given by:

$$p(t) = (x(t),y(t)) = (5+\cos(3t), 4e^{3t})$$

Find the tangent vector when $t = 4$ .

My question is to solve this do i just take the derivative 
of $5+\cos(3t)$ and $4e^{3t}$ 
and then just plug in  $4$ ?

Comment: And then normalise.

Comment: Yes, you could say that by definition, $p'(t)=(x'(t),y'(t))$ when the curve is smooth enough.  Try to use Tex commands to write formulas. It makes your post tidier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *tangent line* at $t = 0$ (convenience) has parametric equation: $T(t) = p(0)+ tp'(0)$. You have $p(0) = (6,4), p'(0) = (0,12)\implies T(t) = (6,4)+t(0,12) = (6,4+12t)$, with $t \in \mathbb{R}$ . I hope this helps. I mistakenly did the case $t = 0$ since it is popular, but you can see how I did it and adjust it to your case $t = 4$. For the *tangent vector* only at say $t = 4$, it is just $v(4) = p'(4) = (x'(4),y'(4))= (-3\sin(12), 12e^{12})$ .